# Laravel Queue Daemon - Memory leak

Tags: laravel, queue, backgroundworker, amazon-sqs, supervisord

I have a Laravel app and have several Daemon Queue Workers running on a server consuming messages from SQS. I know memory is a concern here but I'm having trouble figuring out how to free up memory during / between each job. if I leave the workers  running long enough, the memory usage continues to build up.

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: Why are they running infinitely? Or is it that before one ends another spawns and eventually this will result in the memory being complete consumed.

Comment: Well there are several workers running on one server, so they're processing jobs concurrently.